# searching for a maven filter from the command line

Tags: java, linux, maven, java-ee-6

I tried creating a maven webapp jee6 from the command line with this code:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.henry.tutoria -DartifactId=jee6example 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp-javaee6
```

but on the command line, it returned 253 which has this:

```
253: remote -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart (An archetype which contains a sample Maven project.)
```

I have tried to look at the numbers sequentially but that is so cumbersome. Does anyone know a linux command to search for the number with the webapp-javaee6? perhaps it might not be there as I tried to create this from my mavin plugin in eclipse and all I found was `maven-archetype-webapp` if this is the case, how do I add a jee6 to the maven filter on eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify the artifactGroupId (and the artifactId is slightly different than the one you tried). So the following command line should work:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.henry.tutoria -DartifactId=jee6example -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee6 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes
```

And to answer more precisely to your question. When you see this *huge artifact list* you can type a few chars like `javaee6`+enter to filter the result list. (It will filter against archetypeGroupId or archetypeArtifactId)

Comment: I just want to ask you finally, supposing I wanted to build a hibernate project using maven, do you know what archetypeartifactsId and archetypeGroupId to use? Thanks

Comment: In my experience, it's difficult to find the perfect archetype on the web (you always have some more or less minor change to do). The best is to googling `maven archetype hibernate` and you may find some stuff intersting for your target architecture (but don't search too much for the perfect definitive archetype: it probably doesn't exists... but it's quite easy to create it yourself once you know what you need)